# Meta question: can't find meta

Tags: discussion, openid

Please how do I change my openID email address?

Comment: The answer depends on your OpenID provider, I guess.

Comment: @Caramdir: I think he means how to change the OpenID associated with his account. (Which is done on [the user page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/994/ahmed-musa) by pressing the 'add openid'.